# Not fully understanding fork for switch program output

Tags: c, unix, switch-statement, fork

I have been trying to understand the output of this program, but still I don’t quite get it.

```
main()
{
    int pid, i;
    pid = getpid();

    for (i = 0; i < 25; i++)
    {
        switch (fork())
        {
            case 0:
                if (pid % 2 == 0)
                {
                    exit(0);
                    break;
                }

            default:
                if (pid % 2 != 0)
                {
                    exit(0);
                }
        }
    }

    printf("I am the process %d and my father is the process %d\n", getpid(), getppid());

    while (wait(NULL) > 0) {}

    return 0;
}
```

When I run this, it returns:

> I am the process 11110 and my father is the process 26453

However, if you were to run the above code without both "% 2", it won't return anything.

I am very confused about this. The way I thought it would work (for the code without "% 2") is, for each for iteration:

- the child (pid==0) would finish its process (killing the child process) and always break from the switch (not affecting the for loop)
- the father/main process will wait until the child dies
- next for iteration

Is the above approach correct? If so, how would it be with "% 2"?

Comment: The print statement is missing in your code.

Comment: Apologies. Print statement added

Answer (score 0):

Without `% 2` you'd get:

```
        switch (fork())
        {
        case 0:
            if (pid == 0)
            {
                exit(0);
                break;
            }

        default:
            if (pid != 0)
            {
                exit(0);
            }
        }
```

Since `pid` is not 0, the parent would `exit(0)` immediately after the first `fork()`, so you won't see a print statement.

Comment: That means that the for loop in this case is redundant? What would be the result in the case of % 2?